# Pine script strategy open at second open candel and no when EMA crossover

Tags: xcode, pine-script

whith this strategy i would like to have the open trade in exactly moment of ema crossovers, but all time I have open trade when the next candle open.
It is often a problem because at the ema crossovers I have a bullish push but at the opening of the next candle can be bearish causing the loss of the trade.
Can you help me? thanks

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='MARCO  18/20', overlay=true)
// STEP 1:
// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)



FastPeriod = input.int(title='Fast MA Period', defval=18, group='Moving Average')
SlowPeriod = input.int(title='Slow MA Period', defval=20, group='Moving Average')



TPPerc = input.float(title='Long Take Profit (%)', defval=0.11, group='TP & SL')
SLPerc = input.float(title='Long Stop Loss (%)', defval=4.4, group='TP & SL')

TP_Ratio = input.float(title='Sell Postion Size % @ TP', defval=100, group='TP & SL', tooltip='Example: 100 closing 100% of the position once TP is reached') / 100


// Calculate moving averages
fastSMA = ta.sma(close, FastPeriod)
slowSMA = ta.sma(close, SlowPeriod)

// Calculate trading conditions
enterLong = ta.crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)


// Plot moving averages
plot(series=fastSMA, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='Fase MA')
plot(series=slowSMA, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='Slow MA')

// STEP 2:
// Figure out take profit price
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? math.round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

percentAsPrice(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? (pcnt / 100.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na)

current_position_size = math.abs(strategy.position_size)
initial_position_size = math.abs(ta.valuewhen(strategy.position_size[1] == 0.0, strategy.position_size, 0))

TP = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TPPerc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)
SL = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(SLPerc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)



// Submit entry orders
if enterLong
    strategy.entry(id='Long', direction=strategy.long)



// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit('TP', from_entry='Long', limit=TP, stop=SL)


// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=strategy.position_size > 0 ? TP : na, color=color.new(color.green, 0), style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title='Take Profit')
plot(series=strategy.position_size > 0 ? SL : na, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title='Stop Loss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pine script makes the calculations (runs your code) when the bar closed. After that, if your code has an entry, you can enter a trade on the next trade. Since the bar where you run the script is already closed, the trade will be made on the next trade - `open` price of the next bar. This is basically how real trade will work, since you can't check a trade that already happened and then decide that this trade is good for you or not. You will have to enter on the next trade.

You can override this if you [wish](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/process-orders-close/).

Answer (score 0):

try enabling in settings: recalculate strategy on each tick